# ERROR node_modules/@types/node/globals.d.ts(196,5) errorTS2300: Duplicate identifier 'resolve' src/typings.d.ts(12,3) Duplicate identifier 'resolve'

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

Getting following error after updating app from Angular 5 to 7, using ng update --all --force to update all the dependencies.

ERROR in node_modules/@types/node/globals.d.ts(196,5): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'resolve'.
src/typings.d.ts(12,3): error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'resolve'.

Tried adding this to tsconfig.json file:

```
"exclude": [
      "node_modules",
      "typings/main",
      "typings/main.d.ts",
      "typings/index.d.ts",
      "node_modules/@types/node/globals.d.ts"
    ]
```

and this to package.json:
`"postinstall": "shx rm -rf node_modules/@types/node && echo 'workaround for libs importing @types/node on browser environment'"`

then deleted node modules and did fresh install. Nothing has helped.

this is from node_modules/@types/node/globals.d.ts

```
interface NodeRequireFunction {
    /* tslint:disable-next-line:callable-types */
    (id: string): any;
}

interface NodeRequire extends NodeRequireFunction {
    resolve: RequireResolve; <- duplicate resolve
    cache: any;
    /**
     * @deprecated
     */
    extensions: NodeExtensions;
    main: NodeModule | undefined;
}

interface RequireResolve {
    (id: string, options?: { paths?: string[]; }): string;
    paths(request: string): string[] | null;
}

interface NodeExtensions {
    '.js': (m: NodeModule, filename: string) => any;
    '.json': (m: NodeModule, filename: string) => any;
    '.node': (m: NodeModule, filename: string) => any;
    [ext: string]: (m: NodeModule, filename: string) => any;
}

declare var require: NodeRequire;
```

and this is from typings.d.ts:

```
declare var module: NodeModule;
interface NodeModule {
  id: string;
}
declare var CSSstring: string;
interface NodeRequire {
  cache: any;
  extensions: NodeExtensions;
  main: NodeModule;
  (id: string): any;
  resolve(id: string): string;    <- duplicate resolve
}

declare var require: NodeRequire;
declare module '*.json' {
    const value: any;
    export default value;
}
```

Comment: And what happens when you don't use --force? https://angular.io/cli/update "--force=true|false 
If false, will error out if installed packages are incompatible with the update.

Default: false"

Comment: it wouldn't let me update many of the packages bc of peer dependency requirements, this includes angular core

Comment: Did you follow the upgrade guide for your version changes..? https://update.angular.io/

Comment: tried to but couldn't get past the angular core update bc of the peer dependency issue

Comment: There seems to be plenty of solutions out there for this kind of issue https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10875#issuecomment-394221833

Comment: There are, that is why I used force, many people recommended that, many of the packages in my project required updating together so that is why i did it this way. Why do you have a better suggestion? Not sure if loading all my dependencies individually  is the bast way to solve this problem anyways.

Comment: Your question says you used all with force, the answer I linked was specific with force. The upgrade guide says you'll have to update the failing dependencies manually after, which means checking the versions required / compatibility etc

Comment: I could try it that way, I just was curious if anyone had a solution for this problem of error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'resolve'. Thanks though for the recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

I was receiving a similar error message. I have fixed installing typescript in my project:

```
npm i -D typescript
```

Typescript was installed globally with a previous version not corresponding with @types/node library version in the project

Answer (score 0):

This is happening coz 2 node modules define "resolve"

You can fix this by doing this:

tsconfig.app.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    types: [] // you can list the types you want to use here
  } 
}
```

You prob want to do the same to tsconfig.spec.json if you are unit testing.

Comment: thank you for the recommendation, unfortunately that still did not help, even though I left out node from the types array

Comment: I got it working by changing it resolve: RequireResolve; in the typings.d.ts file, do you think this will lead to problems, the types are not identical?